# unserialize error after emptying cache with Symfony and minimum-stability : dev

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, sonata-admin

I've got an error when I clear manualy the `Symfony` cache after installing the `SonataAdminBundle` in `Symfony 2.1.8` (but I've the same error with the `2.2` or `2.1`)

First, I've installed `Symfony` :

```
php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition Project/ 2.1.8
```

Then updating my composer.json by adding (line per line) :

```
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "2.1.x-dev",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "2.1.x-dev",
    "sonata-project/jquery-bundle": "1.8.x-dev",
    "sonata-project/exporter": "1.*",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.1.x-dev",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.1.x-dev"

    ...
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
```

Apparently the `sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle` bundle needs the minimum-stability to be set at dev.

Finally I've run :

```
    php ../composer.phar update
    rm -rf app/cache/*
    php app/console cache:clear
```

When I load the front page in dev environnement, I've the error :

```
Notice: unserialize() [<a href='function.unserialize'>function.unserialize</a>]: Error at offset 154 of 25784 bytes in /web/Project/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 1316
```

The bootstrap.php.cache load an unserialize the file app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php.meta :

http://pastebin.com/EEZmxWZQ

After multiple tests, it's appears that the "minimum-stability": "dev" broke the clear:cache command.
On a fresh install of Symfony, after adding "minimum-stability": "dev", I've go the error again.

Do you know how to install the Sonata admin bundle without any change on the minimum-stability ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

after some research I found this solution

```
"symfony/symfony"              :"2.1.x@stable",

"sonata-project/intl-bundle"              :"dev-master",
"sonata-project/admin-bundle"             :"2.1.x",
"sonata-project/cache-bundle"             :"dev-master",
"sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle":"2.1.x",
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've tried it, but I've still got :



`Problem 1
    - The requested package sonata-project/admin-bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.`

Here the [composer.json](http://pastebin.com/wAvgrCx4)